# How can I get last week date starting monday to sunday in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, getdate

I want a javascript function that gives me start_date as the last week monday date and end_date as last week sunday date.
So for example, today is 03/09/2016, so I want 
start_date = 02/29/2016
end_date = 03/06/2016

so far I have wriiten the code as

```
        function GetLastWeekDate(){
        start_date = new Date();
        start_date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        end_date = new Date();
        var date=null;
        var curr = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
        var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay("monday"),
             last  = first + 6;

         start_date.setDate( first );
         end_date. setDate( last );
         }


(function() {
     var original = Date.prototype.getDay;
    var daysOfWeek = {
    sunday: 0,
    monday: 1,
    tuesday: 2,
    wednesday: 3,
    thursday: 4,
    friday: 5,
    saturday: 6,
    };

     Date.prototype.getDay = function(weekBegins) {
      weekBegins = (weekBegins || "sunday").toLowerCase();
        return (original.apply(this) + 7 - daysOfWeek[weekBegins]) % 7;
      };
    })();
```

but its giving me date as

```
    03/07/2016 and 03/13/2016
```

how do I fix this to get the dates I want?

Comment: try using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 5):

If in case you just want plain js solution w/out any external libraries. You can try this instead.

```
var dateNow = new Date();
var firstDayOfTheWeek = (dateNow.getDate() - dateNow.getDay()) + 1; // Remove + 1 if sunday is first day of the week.
var lastDayOfTheWeek = firstDayOfTheWeek + 6;
var firstDayOfLastWeek = new Date(dateNow.setDate(firstDayOfTheWeek - 7));
var lastDayOfLastWeek = new Date(dateNow.setDate(lastDayOfTheWeek - 7));
```

In the above solution, firstDataOfLastWeek will be previous week Monday, and lastDayOfLastWeek will be previous week Sunday.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [answer]. Your answer should provide some informations why the suggested code solves the problem. I flagged it as "low quality"

Comment: firstDayOfLastWeek = Sun Mar 22 2020 19:30:05 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)
lastDayOfLastWeek = Wed Feb 26 2020 19:30:05 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)
That's the answer generated by this code on: Wed Apr 01 2020 19:33:46 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)... It's wrong for lastDayOfLastWeek

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of date handling to do, I can only strongly suggest that you use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library.

In this case, the dates would be :

```
var startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'week').startOf('week');
var endDate = moment().subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week');
```

Here you can see it in action :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("fromDate").textContent = moment().subtract(1, "week").startOf("week");
  document.getElementById("toDate").textContent = moment().subtract(1, "week").endOf("week");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>From : <span id="fromDate"></span></p>
    <p>To : <span id="toDate"></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```